# How can I modify the initial configuration of QGIS, using pyQgis?

Tags: pyqgis

I want to modify the initial configuration of QGIS.
I read what can be done with the environment variable PyQGIS_STARTUP, but I do not know how to do it.

What I want is to remove some QToolBar, but before I start QGIS.

I know I can remove it using:

```
main_window.removeDockWidget ([i for i in main_window.findChildren (QDockWidget) if i.windowTitle () == 'Panels'] [0])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of playing around with variables, you could consider using a **startup.py** script which executes your code to hide panels or perform other actions. You could use something like the following:

```
from qgis.utils import iface
from PyQt4.QtGui import QDockWidget

panels = ['Layers Panel', 'Layer Styling', 'Layer Order Panel']

def hidePanels():
    for i in iface.mainWindow().findChildren(QDockWidget):
        if i.windowTitle() in panels:
            i.hide()

iface.initializationCompleted.connect(hidePanels)
```

And save this in your `/.qgis2/python/` directory. Now when you start QGIS, it will immediately hide your panels.

Comment: @MarisolPrado - Most welcome, glad it helped :)